# Docker No MySQL connection to Nginx

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker

I build up a compose file that creates nginx, php, mysql, and phpmyadmin.

Everything is working for itself. 
PHPmyAdmin can talk to the mysql container.
Nginx can talk to php container.

But it seems that nginx or php is not able to talk to mysql. When executing something like

```php
mysql_connect('localhost','florian','pw')
```

it gives back:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
php:
    build: php-docker/.
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/:/var/www/

nginx:
    build: nginx-docker/.
    container_name: nginx
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "80:80"

mysql:
    build: mysql-docker/.
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_USER: florian
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db


  phpmyadmin:
    build: phpmyadmin/.
    links:
     - mysql:db
    ports:
     - 1234:80
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
     PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
     PMA_USERNAME: florian
     PMA_PASSWORD: pw
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
    restart: always
```

Comment: What version of php are you using? Mysql extension has been removed from php7. Use PDO or mysqli

Comment: Can you access MySQL from your host?

Comment: You can't connect to localhost if your MySQL instance runs in other container. First, you need to connect both containers on docker's network, if you wouldn't use the default network. Now you can connects to MySQL container using the container name (in this case mysql) or the IP.

Comment: @GiorgioCerruti I thought I do this with my link statement.

Comment: @frz3993 I use php 7.0. Are you sure? as I get this error in Wordpress. But on my strato host, the exact same wordpress version runs on php7.0

Comment: I am sure @Florian. The error indicates either the extension is not enabled/installed or you are using PHP 7. Wordpress was tested and should be compatible with PHP 7, but I dont know about the plugins

Comment: @frz3993 you were absolutely right, wordpress seems to work around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_connect` function is removed from PHP 7.0.

You have to migrate your code to mysqli extension, which provides similar function `mysqli_connect`, or migrate to PDO.

Reference (look at red warning): http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php